# Django - Syntax Error in def __unicode__(self)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm learning Django from djangobook and in Chapter 6, where the admin app is installed, the `syncdb` command returns a syntax error in `models.py` (`return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)`

I'm using Python 3.

Why this happens? How to fix it?

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website=models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Error:**

```
  File "C:\Users\ken\Desktop\NightHawk\Hawk\books\models.py", line 20
    return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please show us the full exception, plus more context; the lines before should be included.

Comment: I think that with Python 3, you need to define `__str__` methods instead of `__unicode__`. Check if that works for you.

Comment: @Salem is correct.  You need to use `__str__` but I'd also like to point out that the djangobook (by its own admission) is horribly out of date.  I'd recommend that you try effective django or two scoops of django.  Best of luck!

Comment: @KarthikeyanKC weird, that seems right to me. Either way, try to replace it with `return "{0} {1}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)`

Comment: @Salem: that wouldn't throw a syntax error, though.

Comment: @Salem: and the `str % values` syntax works just fine in Python 3. It's the `u''` prefix here that is the problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I was trying this syntax and it worked as expected (3.4). Didn't know that before 3.3 `u` was not supported though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using Python 2 syntax in Python 3. Although Python 3.3 and up support using the `u` prefix for unicode string values (to support cross-version code), Python 3.2 and before *do not*; remove the `u` prefix to make it work:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

However, you will also need to consult the Django [Porting to Python 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods) documentation and use `__str__`, not `__unicode__` here:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

If you are following a specific book, you may want to install Python 2 instead.